# SpringMVC Converter Exception Handling

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I implemented a converter to convert String to UUID and include length validation.

```
public class StringToUUIDConverter implements Converter<String, UUID> {

    public UUID convert(String source){
      if(source.length>36){
         throw new RuntimeException();
       }else{
         return ...
       }
    }
}
```

At first, I thought I would get a RuntimeException when I passed in a string of length 37. However, I tested it and found that no exception was thrown.

Code snippet of TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary()

```
    if (editor == null && conversionService != null && newValue != null && typeDescriptor != null) {
        TypeDescriptor sourceTypeDesc = TypeDescriptor.forObject(newValue);
        if (conversionService.canConvert(sourceTypeDesc, typeDescriptor)) {
            try {
                return (T) conversionService.convert(newValue, sourceTypeDesc, typeDescriptor);
            }
            catch (ConversionFailedException ex) {
                // fallback to default conversion logic below
                conversionAttemptEx = ex;
            }
        }
    }
```

`ConversionUtils` convert all exception to `ConversionFailedException` :

```
abstract class ConversionUtils {

    @Nullable
    public static Object invokeConverter(GenericConverter converter, @Nullable Object source,
            TypeDescriptor sourceType, TypeDescriptor targetType) {

        try {
            return converter.convert(source, sourceType, targetType);
        }
        catch (ConversionFailedException ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            throw new ConversionFailedException(sourceType, targetType, source, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

`TypeConverterDelegate` catches the exception I throw and follows another set of logic to convert String to UUID. Although I've done what I want with `InitBinder`, what should I do if I really want to throw an exception here?

Comment: It doesn't seem to catch `RuntimeException`, only `ConversionFailedException`. There may be something else going on.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar  Thank you for your answer. I added some `ConversionUtils` code fragments, it converts all exceptions to the `ConversionFailedException`.